# Liquid templates: even/odd items in for loop

Tags: jekyll, liquid

If I have a for loop in Liquid (using Jekyll), how can I target even (or odd) items only? I have tried:

```
{% for item in site.posts %}
    {% if forloop.index % 2 == 1 %}
```

but that doesn't seem to work. I have also tried:

```
(forloop.index % 2) == 1
```

and:

```
forloop.index - (forloop.index / 2 * 2) == 1
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I think you'll want to use the cycle tag for this. For example:

```
{% for post in site.categories.articles %}
   <article class="{% cycle 'odd', 'even' %}"></article>
{% endfor %}
```

If you want different HTML markup for each cycle:

```
{% for item in site.posts %}
  {% capture thecycle %}{% cycle 'odd', 'even' %}{% endcapture %}
  {% if thecycle == 'odd' %}
    <div>echo something</div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can find more information on it at [Liquid for Designers](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers), although the example there isn't particularly helpful. This [Shopify support thread](http://forums.shopify.com/categories/2/posts/36447) should also help.

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but the link you found got me the real answer. I edited your answer to include my solution. Thanks!

Comment: Also, your solution would work if I wanted to use CSS only, but I wanted to split `site.posts` into two columns, so only class switching wasn't enough for me.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if you were looking to use CSS or not. Glad to help though!

Comment: Your example works great, although I needed to add an offset to one of my loops to get it to work for me.

Comment: I got the answer, but how come the modulo version doesn't work?

Comment: Sometimes you'll need to mention the collection explicitly (in this case `site.posts`): `{% cycle site.posts: 'odd', 'even' %}` if you reuse the code on multiple pages, for example.

Answer (score 38):

In contrast to what the [Shopify support thread](http://forums.shopify.com/categories/2/posts/36447) in [Ales Lande's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8980590/6884) says, there **is** a `modulo` function in Liquid - in form of [the `modulo` filter](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/math-filters#modulo).

With it, you can do this:

```
{% for item in site.posts %}
    {% assign mod = forloop.index | modulo: 2 %}
    {% if mod == 0 %}
        <!-- even -->
    {% else %}
        <!-- odd -->
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I like this solution better than the one using `cycle`; solving a mathematical problem using a string seems... odd!

Comment: This solution will not work if you conditionally skip anything within the loop, such as looping through site.collections but trying to leave 'posts' (standard collection) out.