# How to count items in a for loop? Build a grid with a for loop that closes correctly?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

My problem is this: I want to build a grid with two items each row. The following loop works perfect with even numbers of items like 2,4,6,... because the grid closes correctly with a `</div><!-- /.row -->`.

```
{% for image in page.image %}
    {% cycle '<div class="row">', '' %}
        <div class="large-6 columns">{% image bigthumb {{ image }} class="th" %}</div><!-- /.large-6.columns -->
    {% cycle '', '</div><!-- /.row -->' %}
{% endfor %}
```

**But** if I have an odd/uneven number of items my grid won't get its necessary closing `</div>`. How can I solve this problem in liquid?

Comment: A [post about even and odd items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980192/liquid-templates-even-odd-items-in-for-loop) may help you. But if not, perhaps "`if forloop.last` close the <div>", before the second cycle, and then `if not forloop.last` around the cycle may also work.

Comment: Isn't there a simple way to ask "if items number even do this" and "if items number odd do that"? at the end i could than just ask "is it the last item? if it's odd please add something"...

Comment: There is a modulo filter. I don't know if you can `capture` the result of that and use it as a variable.

Comment: I am sure I will solve the problem. Thank you Paulo for helping me out.